# select only columns with values not matching between two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get only columns which have different values in SQL SERVER?

```
TABLE 1
id            Name                     Desig
1             Ali                      Assistant.Manager
1             Ali                      Manager
2             John                     Manager
```

Now if i want to check status of id 1, it should return Designation(i.e Assistant.Manager & Manager)

Comment: Which database are you using?  Does it matter which of the designations are returned, or can it be a random one?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2
i want only column which is changed previously, not all the columns

Comment: How would you determine "previously"?  A SQL table is a set of unordered rows, if you do not have a column to sort on, there is no way to determine which row is first

Comment: i have table id column with identity (1,1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.Desig
FROM TableName T1 JOIN
(SELECT id,name
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id,name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Desig) > 1) T2
ON T1.id=T2.id AND T1.name=T2.name
```

Result:

```
DESIG
Assistant.Manager
Manager
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb37d3/8).

Comment: In the above example i have used only 3 columns, but if there are 40, 50 columns in a table and only 2,3 column values are changed. 
Is there any way i can get only those 2,3 columns which are previously changed

Comment: @user2625113: No, you have to specify the column names in the query.

Answer (score 0):

If `id` is an identity, as you comment, you can choose the latest row per name like:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (
                    partition by name
                    order by id desc) as rn
        ,       *
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   rn = 1 -- Latest row per name
```